# Would like a script that puts a checklist into a photoshop file - possible?

Tags: scripting, photoshop

I'd like to run an action that places text into the file. It would be a checklist of things for my employees to cross reference before saving out a file. The only way I can think to do this would be to somehow place a text document into the file? Is there anyway to create a script that does this so that every time I set up a file I can run it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is first create your checklist in photoshop and save as a jpeg, transparent png, or psd.

[image: checklist jpeg]

Open a Photoshop project you want to apply the checklist to.

Go to Window > Actions (Alt + F9)

In the **Actions Window**, click the **Create new set** button, Name it Checklist.

[image: create new set]

Click the **Create new action** button, name it Import.

Click **Record**.

[image: create new action]

**Drag and Drop** the Checklist Jpeg you saved into your project.

Click the **Stop** button.

It will add **Place** to the Actions.

You can save your Actions to a file.

Replay that Action in any Project to import the Checklist to it.

[image: Place]

If you want to go a step further and have the text be editable, if you saved as psd.

- While recording
- Right Click the Checklist Layer (Which has been turned into a Smart Object).
- Click Edit Contents.
- Drag and Drop the Text back over into your project.
- Close out of the Edit
- Delete the old Smart Object.
- Click Stop.